# Vertical Navigation Bar Height Issue

Tags: html, css, web

Basically everything is working fine except the scroll bar shows up on pages where it's not needed and when the page is resized the navbar won't extend down with it and will end up like this (Image Below), You can see the navigation bar won't extend down with the moved content of the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QynSv.png

Here is a JSFiddle link, any help would be greatly appreciated!
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pq3t70th/1/

Navigation CSS Code

```
nav {
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-color:black;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    background-color: #3b5999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 180px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `display: table-cell;` for `section` and `nav`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ishimdar/ec95kv65/)

Comment: hm, after testing it I realized it brought another problem to the table (Image Below)

http://i.imgur.com/IRtpT6r.png

The nav bar doesn't go down the entire page and only goes up to where it needs to :\

Comment: I am not able to understand, basically what u want?

Comment: Hm, you can't notice the issue on jsfiddle, however if you look on codepen you will be able to see that the navbar doesn't go down the whole page like it's supposed to.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVjoqg?editors=110